# Child Component in Parent Component is calling different function on click React

Tags: reactjs

When I am clicking  on button 2 first it is calling function 1 not function 2,  I want if click button1 should call function 1 and if click on button2  should call function 2

it is working fine if click button 1 first then button 2 next, but it is calling function 2 if I click button 2 first

```
const function1 =()=>
{
   alert('function 1 called')
}

const function2 =()=>
{
   alert('function 2 called')
}
```

parent Component

```
const ParentComponent = () =>
{
  return(
       <ChildComponent onChange={function1} />
       //Button 1

       <ChildComponent onChange={function2} />
      //Button 2
  )
}
```

child Component

```
const ChildComponent = (props) =>
{
    return(
        <>
            <div className='button'>
                <label htmlFor='single'>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faImage} color='#3B5998' size='5x' />
                </label>
                <input type='file' id='single' onChange={props.onChange} />
            </div>
        </> 

    )
}
```

Comment: What buttons are being clicked? There are none in your example code snippets. `function1` and `function2` appear to be very independent from each other, so there's not any specific order in which either will be called other then by how you interact with the inputs to trigger the `onChange` events to happen.

Comment: child  component itself is a FontAwesomeIcon icon button

Comment: Buttons typically have `role="button"` if not already a semantic `button` HTML element, and will have an `onClick` event handler. This is splitting hairs though. I don't see anything in your example code that would make one callback be called before, or after, the other. There are two instances of your "button" and each operate independent of the other. If button 1 is clicked first, then `function1` is called first, and if button 2 is clicked first, then `function2` is called first. Outside of this it's unclear what any issue/problem may be. Can you clarify for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id='single'` this part should be unique per DOM element.